# Chrome Save-As webpage-complete times out, Firefox saves instantly

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I am trying to save a web page I am viewing in Chrome using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (Save As) and using the default "webpage complete" option.

I can view the web page perfectly fine in the browser.

However, the save operation runs at an absolute crawl and doesn't ever complete, and often times out.

[image]

When I do the exact same operation in Firefox the save happens instantaneously.

I tried looking at the Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools, but nothing appeared when I started the save operation, which is even more puzzling to me.

I am not running an ad-blocker, as the site has ad-blocker detection and won't function with ad-blocking enabled.

- What is happening here?
- Could some javascript "anti-save" script be the cause?
- How can I save the webpage in Chrome?

Comment: Both saving to the same directory?  Not a permissions problem or anything?

Comment: No differences in destination filename, so not a permissions issue, no.